# Aligning multiple array environment vertically (at the bottom)

Tags: vertical-alignment, environments, arrays

I have multiple array environment that I want to allign vertically. 
Currently it looks like:
[image]

With a minimal working example being:

```
\begin{array}{|c  c|}
    \hline A_1^1 & A_1^2 \\
     A_2^1 & A_2^2 \\
   \hline
\end{array} \, 
\begin{array}{|c  c|}
    \hline B^1 & B^2 \\
   \hline
\end{array}
```

It alligns them in the center. I want them to align them at the bottom. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `\begin{array}[b]` in both cases.